# Windows Server 2016 or Cisco 1900 router as vpn device for a connection with active directory authentification?

Tags: active-directory, vpn, windows-server-2016, cisco-vpn

I am relatively new to vpns, so please excuse me if my question is a little bit off.

In my test scenario i have a small company network with a client to site vpn. This network contains a DC, Fileserver, Sharepoints and so on...
Users of the vpn connection should only authenticate with their AD accounts.
The vpn server is the last thing that has to be implemented but i do not know which solution i should use. I did some research an came across two solutions.
- Windows Server 2016 with RRAS
- Cisco Router

Question 1:
Can someone please explain me the differences between these two solutions in case of performance, security and scalability?

Question 2:
How do you implement AD authentication on an Cisco 1900 Router?

Comment: Question 1, its opinion based imo, question 2 search radius, and come back if you got problem to implement it.

Comment: What solution would you prefer? Windows/Linux server or Cisco router? @yagmoth555

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: My preference is to have the VPN terminate at the router.  Then you are controlling access at the boundary of your network.

For your second question: AD authentication can be done either with a radius server or LDAP server.  LDAP is slightly easier because you just need the right LDAP configuration.  Radius would require deployment of NAP role on a server along with some policy configuration.

See [AAA LDAP Configuration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_ldap/configuration/15-mt/sec-usr-ldap-15-mt-book/sec_conf_ldap.html)